# Magento front end not redirecting properly on localhost. But admin works

Tags: magento

Hello I currently backed up my magento files on my live server to put them on my local server. My backend seems to be working fine but my front end doesn't. This is the message I get 
"The page isn't redirecting properly
Firefox has detected that the server is redirecting the request for this address in a way that will never complete.
This problem can sometimes be caused by disabling or refusing to accept cookies."

I would be glad if someone could help me. Thank you.

Comment: Is there any log inside var/log ?

Comment: Clear cache from megento and `reindex` your data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ok so after hours of fidgeting around with the back-end and database. I made it work by making changes in the config_data file in the database. One has to make sure he replaces all urls to local. I had redirected the urls earlier but I just found out i was missing one. In the last row of that table.I hope this helps someone.